# Number of nonsingular $2\times2$ matrices over $GF(3)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, group-theory, discrete-mathematics

> Let $G=GL(2,GF(3))$ be the group of all matrices $
>         \begin{pmatrix}
>         a & b \\
>          c & d
>         \end{pmatrix}
> $ whose determinants are nonzero and whose entries $a,b,c,d$ are taken from the finite field $GF(3)=\{0,1,2\}$. Show that $o(G)$, the number of matrices in the group $G$, is $48$.

Well, because there are $3$ possibilites for $a,b,c,d$ it will be $3^4 = 81$, now I'm struggling finding the $33$ possibilites which have to come from $ ad = bc$. How can I find them? I counted till $18$, but it's not enough.

Comment: Presumable you actually mean the elements to be in the finite field with $3$ elements?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft $\{a,b,c,d \in 0,1,2\}$

Comment: The point is that $\left | \begin {array} {c c} 1&2 \\2 & 1 \end {array} \right |$ has determinant $0$, not $3$, in the finite field with $3$ elements.  You need to be in that field to get closure so you have a group.

Comment: Sorry, but $\{a,b,c,d\in 0,1,2\}$ is complete gibberish from a mathematical point of view.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft then add mod3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the matrix has non-zero determinant,the columns are linearly independent.

For the first column of a $2\times 2$ matrix we have $3\times 3$ choices .But both the entries can't be zero so $9-1$ choices.

For the second column of a $2\times 2$ matrix we have $3\times 3$ choices. But the columns must be linearly independent hence can't be a scalar multiple of one another,hence $9-3=6$ choices.

In total $8\times 6=48$ choices

Comment: nice proof! thank you

Comment: One equivalent manner of viewing this is the following: there is a bijection between $GL(2,3)$ and the set of all ordered basis of the 2-dimensional vector space over $GF(3)$. Now you only have to figure out how many such sets you may encounter. Well, for the first element you could get any of the $3^2-1=8$ non-zero elements in the vector space and for second and last element in the basis you should only avoid the vectors that lie on the "line" generated by the first element you've included in the basis. This way you must pick one out of $3^2-3=6$ elements. Total: $8\times 6=48$.